# SwiftUI: @FetchRequest For Core Data is not Working

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, swiftui

I am using a simple coredata model and I have an Entity that is called `Movements` and it has 4 fields, `date`, `category`, `description`, `amount`.

This the view:

```
struct TransactionsView: View {
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var managedObjectContext
    @FetchRequest(entity: Movements.entity(), sortDescriptors: []) var transactions:FetchedResults<Movements>
    @State private var showAddModal = false;

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            List {
                    ForEach(transactions, id: \.id) { t in
                        Text(t.desc ?? "No Cat")
                    }
            }
        }
    }
}
struct TransactionsView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
         return TransactionsView()
    }
}
```

I used the same code for another model, categories, and it worked. For some reason here the previ keeps crashing with a generic error, I have no idea that says basically that `my app has crashed`.

I thought that maybe `Transaction` could be a reserved word and renamed to `Movements` but still the same error.
Is there also a way to debug the @FetchRequest to see the data returned?

Comment: I think you have to have sort descriptors. I think they are mandatory.